# Please help me to create trigger on object Name " Booking"

Tags: trigger

If Booking Status is 'Confirmed' then 
+Room number is required,
+Check in Time is required,
+Check Out Time is required.

Please check my below trigger code is not working

```
trigger bookingTrigger1 on Booking__c (before insert,after insert) {
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for(Booking__c bkg : Trigger.New){
        IF((bkg.Status__c = 'Not Confirmed'&& 
               (bkg.Room_No__c != Null) &&
                  (bkg.Check_In_Time__c!=Null)&& 
                  (bkg.Check_Out_Time__c!=Null)));
        }
bkg.addError('On confirmed status the other field is required')
}
```

Comment: You said the condition is bkg.Status__c == 'Confirmed' but your code says its, 'Not Confirmed'. Take  a look into that. And use '==' instead of '='. I think the trigger should be before update, befor insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably only want this trigger to run before insert and before update and not after insert. However, you should be able to accomplish this via validation rules vs a trigger. If you do stick with the trigger then watch your conditional line as it has only 1 equal sign which is an assignment vs conditional try "==" instead.

`bkg.Status__c = 'Not Confirmed'` `should be bkg.Status__c == 'Not Confirmed'`

Based on your description it sounds like you'd want the conditional to be:

```
         IF(bkg.Status__c == 'Confirmed'&& 
                   (bkg.Room_No__c == Null ||
                    bkg.Check_In_Time__c==Null|| 
                    bkg.Check_Out_Time__c==Null)) {
                      bkg.addError('On confirmed status the other field is required');
         }
```

Comment: I required in confirmed status only;  if(bkg.Status='Confirmed')

Comment: @user28787 your code shows Not Confirmed but whatever the status should be you need either == 'Confirmed' or != 'Confirmed'

Comment: I change the status Confirmed.... but still is not working... somewhere in code it's wrong

Comment: @user28787 if you want to require room no and check in time and check out time when status is confirmed then I believe the above updated condition will work for you - it states when confirmed and any of the 3 fields are null then add error.

Comment: @user28787 also just relized you didn't have the add error inside the if condition body. Use brackets in your conditions makes it easier to work with when new - It looks like you originally were adding the error outside the for loop.

Comment: trigger bookingTrigger1 on Booking__c (before insert,after insert) {
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for(Booking__c bkg : Trigger.New){
        IF(bkg.Status__c == 'Confirmed'&& 
           (bkg.Room_No__c == Null ||
            bkg.Check_In_Time__c==Null|| 
            bkg.Check_Out_Time__c==Null))
    }
        
    else{
bkg.addError('On confirmed status the other field is required');
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37979/discussion-between-jenny-b-and-user28787).

Comment: It's not working properly... when i put status ' Confirmed' then it saved the booking.... It must show the error when i saved the booking

Comment: Are you updating or inserting a record? Make sure you have before insert and before update for the trigger. Also, there is a link for a chat room so the comments don't get too long can you go there?

Comment: I change the trigger event before (update,before insert).... still i am getting error.. when i put all value in field. "Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
On confirmed status the other field is required"

Comment: One more question in this...

Comment: I want to put in trigger is that, when else {(Check_In_Time < Check_Out_Time)} (but its not working.

Comment: @user28787 please ask a new question with your updated code and what you expect to happen that isn't happening.